# pacman: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libpsl.so.5: undefined symbol: u_strFromUTF8_59

Tags: manjaro, pacman

I'm using Arch Linux, and in an attempt to install Virtualbox, I'm very confused.

Now, if I try to use `pacman`, I always get an error:

```
pacman: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libpsl.so.5: undefined symbol: u_strFromUTF8_59
```

I do not know how to fix the problem. Attempts to find a solution led to nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I was able to slove this by manually downloading, untaring then copying the libpsl and libidn2 packages into my system.